# How to Solve Error 0x4260: Controller Enable Signal Lost in Axis, StateDWord 0x21a1301 in beckhoff twincat3 NC-PTP Motion?

Tags: motion, twincat, cnc, industrial, twincat-ads

The beckhoff Twincat system is connected to two axes via the Ethercat bus. Axis 1 and Axis 2 are running at 2000 degrees per second and 300 degrees per second,just using MC_MoveVelocity Function Block； respectively, and the following error is reported after approximately 1 hour and 20 minutes of operation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLiMn.png)

Error 2023/10/23 11:33:55 169 ms | 'TCNC' (500): 'Axis 2' (Axis-ID: 2, Grp-ID: 2): The axis or a coupled slave axis has lost its controller enable signal while executing a command => error 0x4260 (StateDWord: 0x21a1301, CoupleState: 0, ActPos: 1525883.866652, ActVelo: 299.993040)
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error 2023/10/23 11:33:55 169 ms | 'TCNC' (500): 'Axis 1' (Axis-ID: 1, Grp-ID: 1): The axis or a coupled slave axis has lost its controller enable signal while executing a command => error 0x4260 (StateDWord: 0x21a1301, CoupleState: 0, ActPos: 10371623.101616, ActVelo: 1999.996639)

After consulting the Twincat NC error documentation, the following was found：
[text](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tckintransformation/513129739.html&id=)
4260
16992
Monitoring
"Controller enable" Controller enable for the axis or for a coupled slave axis is not present (see axis interface PlcToNc). This error occurs if the controller enable is withdrawn while an axis or a group of axes (also a master/slave group) is being actively positioned. The error also occurs if a PTP axis or a coupled slave axis is started without controller enable.

I have checked the Twincat3 PLC code, and through online SCOPE monitoring, I found that the BOOL variable Enable in the MC_POWER function block is always TRUE, until the fault occurs, the variable is always TRUE.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHY8E.png)

Comment: We encountered this issue when running in a VM. Note that the controller enable signal must be copied from the axis task in to the plc task. If the tasks are not properly scheduled due to overloads then this copying might be compromised and this error can occur. 
Do you run in a VM?

Comment: Yes, I finally realized that it was due to a Task taking up a lot of CPU that caused the error to occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at high rotation speeds, the value of GVL.Axis_Pos_WithRefZero_WithRepair_BeforeRounding[i] will be very large, which will cause the calculation of GVL.Axis_Pos_WithRefZero_WithRepair_AfterRounding[i] consume a lot of CPU resources when calculating GVL.
my code uses multiple functions (e.g. ConvertRangeTo360, ConvertRangeTo240, etc.) to limit the angle values to a specific range. These functions use a loop structure, and if the input angle value is very large, then the function needs to execute a large number of loops, which can consume a lot of CPU resources.